# rand() behavior not understood

Tags: c, random

I have a simple program to generate N pairs of random numbers in C.

I am using `rand()` for this. The value of N is a command line parameter.

I noticed that it always generates the same stream of digits when the passed command line arg is the same.

The `rand()` manpage says that if there is no explicit seed, the RNG is implicitly seeded by value 1 (there no call to `srand()` in my program).

Then however, when I call my program with arg=10 and then with arg=12, I should see the first 10 digits of both sequences as equal, right? (They will be both using the same seed, namely 1). This is not happening. It looks like the seed is being derived and applied from the arg passed implicitly, but that doesn't seem likely. Any ideas?

**Update:** [Sorry for not posting this earlier]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{  
    int objs=100, i;  
    if (argc >= 2)  
        objs = atoi(argv[1]);

     for(i=0; i<objs; i++){
         int p = rand() % objs;
         int q = rand() % objs;
         printf("%d %d\n", p, q);
      }
      return 0;
}
```

I am using Ubuntu 12 and gcc 4.7.2.

Comment: We can't debug a program we can't see.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int objs=100, i;
        if (argc >= 2)
                objs = atoi(argv[1]);

        for(i=0; i<objs; i++){
                int p = rand() % objs;
                int q = rand() % objs;
                printf("%d %d\n", p, q);
        }
        return 0;
}

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Then again, SO isn't really a debugging service :-)

Comment: done. the auto formatting of code doesn't work in comments it seems.

Comment: For information, rand() uses oldest and simple Linear congruential generator(LCG) method to generate psuedo random number generator.

Comment: @SunEric That is not true — the implementation is free to use any PRNG to implement `rand`. For example, glibc `rand()` used by Linux systems implements a nonlinear additive feedback random number generator providing a large period and equal randomness of all bits of output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The int version of rand will generate random numbers from 0 to RAND_MAX. Those ints will be the same with the same seed. But, there must be another step in your code which converts that number to one in the range 0-10 or 0-12. That scaling will be responsible for the different of output.

For example, if it uses division, and rand returns 25, then:

```
// for range 0..10,
25 / 11 => 2 (truncated)

// for range 0..12,
25 / 13 => 1 (truncated)
```

Comment: I fail to understand how a difference in truncation of the result of `rand()` would affect subsequent values returned by `rand()`.

Comment: I take that back, after seeing OP's code, this answers the question.

Comment: Yes. Now that we know the code uses mod, it's clear. Say the first `rand()` returns 20. `20 % 10` is 0, but `20 % 12` is 8. So the same random values will produce different output.

Comment: @user4815162342: correct, the truncation wouldn't, unless the different results caused subsequent code to call rand a different number of times.

Comment: @Douglas That `rand` is called a different number of times is irrelevant because the first `n` calls still produce the same values, and this is what the OP explicitly asks. However, as they are then remaindered with different moduli, the resulting numbers differ. +1

Answer (score 1):

based on the code posted, it appears the difference in output is due to the modulus of the random number being performed.

Answer (score 0):

the first 10 digits of both sequences are not equal, because `rand()` returns the same value (we call a) with the same seed (managed by `srand()` function), but statement `a % objs`will return different values depending on the value of objs. Notice that `a % 12` mean bring a divide by 12 and get its remainder, so when %12 and %10, we will get different value.

hope this will help you